# windows phone app development

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am completely new to windows phone development.
Now I have a PC with windows 7 installed on it. So I only can make apps for windows Phone 7. The apps I make, will they also run on windows phone 8?

And also, do you guys have any good starting tutorials for this?

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WP7 apps will run on WP8.  Use your favorite search engine to find tutorials or post a new question explaining what specifically you can't figure out.